# Session not working with subdomains in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, session-cookies, subdomain

I have one main domain and 4 subdomains on testing site. In bootstrap.php I write a code `ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");` and it works with sessions within all subdomains. But yesterday when I put it on live site, Subdomains threw an

> error 301 Too many redirects

I have fixed that, but session problem still exist. I don't know why it not works on live site, although I have copied exactly same files from testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In APP/config/core.php, set

```
 Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

Other wise your HTTP_HOST check will fail.